# Grails on tomcat waiting indefinitely

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, grails

I deployed my first ever grails app on Tomcat installed on slicehost.  I have installed sun java 6, tomcat 6, and mysql.  I've created the grails war file and uploaded it to the server.  When i browse to the site, I get an indefinite loading.  The same thing happens when I attempt to view the built in tomcat servlet examples.  Did I configure servlets incorrectly?  Also I am getting the "Tomcat Successfully Installed" page, so I don't know what the issue could be.

Thank you,

Comment: How big is the slice?  Sounds like a lot for a small slice.

Comment: I think you should check tomcat log file to know if there is a problem

Answer (score 0):

Check the catalina.out and there should be a file which begins with localhost_.
Please take a look at those files and see if you see any errors